# Change local time by C++ program

Tags: c++, windows-7

Now in my country the local time is:

```
3:43 PM
```

Can I write program in C++ to change the time on a Windows 7 system to another time?

For example set it to 5:00 PM (increase) or decrease it?

Comment: Please provide some more context, do you want to change the system time if so on which OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VC++ you can try. Include the Windows.h header file.

[SetSystemTime Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724942.aspx)

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
st.wYear = 2010;
st.wMonth = 5;
st.wDay = 2;
st.wHour = 7;
st.wMinute = 46;
st.wSecond = 31;
st.wMilliseconds = 345;
::SetSystemTime(&st);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include Windows.h

BOOL WINAPI SetSystemTime(const SYSTEMTIME *lpSystemTime);
```